# Converting this Formula into Google Sheet Script but unable to do this

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using below formula and trying to convert it into Google Sheet App Script. Because I am using number of such conditions with that formula to populate a single result.

And this formula is becoming bigger and bigger day by day. So looking forward to your response if someone can replace it with a script so i will try to replace other conditions as well.

I have tried to replace it but it was not working even a single line.

Your help will be highly appreciated for this issue.

```
    =IFERROR(IF(AND($B5<>"",$H5<>""), 
    IF(AND($H5<>"",$I5<>""), 

    IF(OR(AND(DATEDIF($J5,$H5,"D")<1095,$AE5="")),"***MADE ( " &TEXT($H5,"MM-DD-YYYY")&")- " & 
    
IF(AND(DATEDIF($J5,$H5,"D")<1095,$AE5=""), " MIS? "&",",""),"***MADE ( " &TEXT($H5,"MM-DD-YYYY")&")- " &" COMPLETE -2021 ")& 

    IF(OR(AND(DATEDIF($J5,$H5,"D")<1095,$AE5<>""))," DONE=> "& 

    IF(AND(DATEDIF($J5,$H5,"D")<1095,$AE5<>""),"MIS "&TEXT($AE5," MM.DD.YYYY "&", "),""),"")&"***","*******"),"*******"),"ERROR")
```

Here is the attached Sheet where formula works and give the result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v3CP7D0V13Tr3ykwPQNkpYVuEB6uNrQjqtwq2bx20-8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? And also, can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have attached the sheet but the script i created was for a single line which was not efficient way to do this. If you can please help me with this Formula to replace with code i can do the remaining by my own.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Have you tried the answer below? What is exactly this function doing for you, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: thank you for the asking @Kessy I have tried but still stuck and forgotten to do that.  the sheet i have attached above has formula in Col"AN" which present the result. So i just want that someone who is expert can convert this formula into script it will be huge help for me. Because once this formula will be converted i will convert other as well that formula contains multiple conditions if it has convert in script once can easily add or subtract the conditions by using script.

Comment: You have to see how apps script works and try it for yourself. By checking the documentation and other guides you will then be able to start coding. If then you have an issue with the code, eg. documentation says x I got y, then after searching for other posts you would then ask a question. Stack overflow is not a code-writing service, please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @Kessy thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're making a pretty tedious request for someone to undergo. However, since you say you haven't gotten a single line to work, I'll provide one example below. Hopefully that gets you started, but you probably should consider taking a course or following some videos before asking for more help. A couple I would recommend are:

- [Ben Collins Courses](https://www.benlcollins.com/)
- [Learn Google Sheets Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8p19gUXJYTsUPEpusHgteQ)

Both are run by good guys.

Spreadsheet formula:

`IF(AND($H5<>"",$I5<>""),`

Would be scripted as...

```
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(ss.getRange("i5").getValue()!='' &&
    ss.getRange("h5").getValue()!=''){
      //code for when true

  }
```